# How to pass ID of selected dropdown-list to partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have an index view which has a dropdown list:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ABC", (SelectList) ViewBag.ABC,
    "-- Select item --", new { @onchange ="funcVes(this.value)"})
```

```html
<div id="Vresult">

</div>
```

---

the JavaScript for which is located to the top of this index view, which says

```
function funcVes(e) {
    alert(e);
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $('#tabsDiv').show();
    $('#Vresult').load('/ABC/PartialAction?id=' + e);
};
```

`PartialAction` method does this:

```
public ActionResult PartialAction(int id) {
    return PartialView("_PVIEW");
}
```

Now, `_PVIEW` has many textbox fields which i require to be populated with from the controller side

_PVIEW

```
@model Project.ViewModels.VD

//...scripts
//...begin form..

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Main_ID) //for dropdownlist
//...20 similar boxes for related information pertaining to that dropdownlist
```

VIEW MODEL

contains both the index model and underlying model that the partial view is built on

```
public class VD
{
    public int? Main_ID { get; set; }

    public a aa { get; set; } //underlying models/tables which contain the information for the 20 textboxes to be filled out
    public b bb{ get; set; } //index model
}
```

i basically need to fill out this view depending on the dropdown list selection...

changed both the index and partial view to use same view model that contain both their independent models.

Any help with passing the id that was selected from the drop down list to the textbox contained on the partial view via controller/javascript and its related infor to other tables?

Answer (score 0):

Your `PartialAction` does not fetch any data or provide a model to its view. As you are using `$.load` with a partial view, there is no data or model provided from the "current loaded page". The `PartialAction` server request is completely independent, so needs to fetch its own data.

You can simply set the property of an instance of your VD model and provide the model to the view like this:

```
public ActionResult PartialAction(int id) {
    var data = someDataModel.Find(id);
    var vm = new VD()
    {
       Main_ID = id,
       aa = data.aa,
       bb = data.bb
    };
    return PartialView("_PVIEW", vm);
}
```

If you use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler), or the Chrome F12 "Network" tab, to watch network traffic you will see the raw pages being passed and what is in them. This may help you understand the relationship between requests and views.

Comment: @Newbie101: Apparently you think you updated it, but your changes are not visible :)

Comment: ps @TrueBlueAussie ur ans was able to grab the id for me... now how do i push it (as well as all the related fields that pertain to this id) back out to the field on the partial view that has the corresponding model boxes set up?

Comment: @Newbie101: Does my update help? I do not know what data model you are using, so I just put in a dummy placeholder (that looks a bit like an Entity Framework `Find` call)

Comment: yes, this was exactly the track that i was on, however i have to do this for multiple forms and was wondering if there is an easy way to load all the fields (which actually belong to one table)? but somehow the data is not displaying in the view. i tried it with the Main_ID field only and its not showing

Comment: @Newbie101: At this point you really need to show complete code as the problem may lay elsewhere